# Spaghetti plots collapses in time points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new in R. I am trying to make spaghetti plots of 15 subjects. My "x" axis is TIME, while my "y" axis is DV/PRED or DV/IPRED. The identification of each subject is PTID.

Data looks like this

```
      PTID TIME      DV_PRED     DV_IPRED
1       1    0           NA           NA
2       1   20           NA           NA
3       1   30           NA           NA
4       1   45           NA           NA
5       1   60  0.597961943   0.59642775
6       1  120  0.663766390   0.81470202
7       1  180  0.341640122   0.52077325
8       1  240  1.028288478   1.68708018
9       1  300  0.234030039   0.39264820
10      1  360  0.886066742   1.49238007
11      1  420  0.038982026   0.06546675
12      2    0           NA           NA
13      2   10           NA           NA
14      2   20           NA           NA
15      2   30           NA           NA
16      2   45           NA   1.09824094
17      2   60  1.843748969   0.84627028
18      2  120  1.543101642   1.02708456
```

I have multiple NAs that I just want to ignore.

My code looks like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=TIME, y=DV_IPRED, group=PTID)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 430, by = 30),limits=c(0, 430))+
  xlab("Time (minutes)")+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1, 10), breaks=c(0.1,0.5, 1,2,10))+
  ylab("Observed/Predicted")+
  geom_abline(intercept = log(1), slope = 0,colour="grey", size = 1)+
  theme_bw()+ theme(legend.position="none", 
                    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                    text = element_text(size=8))

print(plot)
```

My problem is that I get a figure collapsing in time points, that looks like this:

[image: bad spaghetti plot]

Any thoughts? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I did na.omit(df) before putting data in shared code.

Comment: Your code is correct and your plot is not a bad spaghetti plot. Why do you think it is wrong ?

Comment: When I plot the provided data, I do not see any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In my mind, there should not be vertical lines in this plot at TIME points 45, 60, 120,180, 240 (the measuring points). That is why I think it is wrong. I can not figure out what is it. Thanks again for your answers!